# Coverting text file to array in IDL

Tags: arrays, text-files, idl

I was looking for a way to convert the following textfile:

```
7.73E+01
7.29E+01
7.06E+00
6.84E+00
6.70E+00
6.45E+00
6.12E+00
5.93E+00
```

Into an IDL array

```
array = [7.73E+01,7.29E+01,7.06E+00,6.84E+00,6.70E+00,6.45E+00,6.12E+00,5.93E+00]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple file like you show, you can just do:

```
n_lines = file_lines(filename)
array = fltarr(n_lines)

open, lun, filename, /get_lun
readf, lun, array
free_lun, lun
```

It can get more complicated if the text file is not just a single value per line and every line is part of the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just curious, how would it work if the file is made up of multiple columns? Would I need to use an IDL equivalent of the python split method?

Comment: Not if everything was the same non-string, datatype. You could do it the same way by just declaring `array = fltarr(n_cols, n_rows)` with everything else the same. If you have different datatypes and/or strings, then you would probably have to use `STRSPLIT` as you mention.